# Nested template tag does not render page in vuejs 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I want to make a table that expands with a click. I am trying to reproduce this example https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/basics/#expandable-rows, however for some reason the  nested tag gives a problem when rendering. I did some tests, if I use the following code only the word **bye** is displayed.

```
<template>
  <h1>bye</h1>
  <template>
    <h1>hi</h1>
  </template>
</template>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You have to tell Vue how and when to render a nested template tag.  See the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-special-elements.html#template):

> The special handling for `<template>` is only triggered if it is used with one of these directives:
>
> - `v-if`, `v-else-if`, or `v-else`
> - `v-for`
> - `v-slot`
>
> **If none of those directives are present then it will be rendered as a native `<template>` element instead.**

In your case, because you've not given any of the above directives, `<template>` is just the native HTML template element. These elements don't get rendered unless through JavaScript as described in the
[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template)

> The `<template>` HTML element is a mechanism for holding HTML that is not to be rendered immediately when a page is loaded but may be instantiated subsequently during runtime using JavaScript.

If you're trying to make the inner `<h1>hi</h1>` a hidden, expandable element, you'll **need** to provide some kind of `v-if` directive anyways to control that behavior, and once you do, you'll give it the ability to be rendered.